# python 2 xml to sort and remove duplicates

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, python-2.6

How to continue a code to sort and delete duplicates before print?
type_id contains many repetitions

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.dom.minidom import *
xml = parse('1.xml')
name = xml.getElementsByTagName('type_id')
for node in name:
    print node.childNodes[0].data.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you need and what the input looks like?

Comment: <type_id>hash_A1="abcDBE31EB5AD4D6897072469B31"</type_id>   etc...   it is a lot of repeating conclusion in the field of type_id to sort in alphabetical order and to remove duplicates

Comment: So you have a list of XML elements named "type_id" that are in a flat hierarchy and all containing only a string that you want to save and print sorted alphabetically? Where's the problem exactly? What do you mean by duplicates in your question? Exact same text inside type_id?

Comment: yes the identical text in  <type_id>hash=qazwsxed5</type_id>
<type_id>hash=qazwsxed5</type_id>
<type_id>hashqwerty</type_id>
<type_id>hashqwerty</type_id>
<type_id>asdasdasd</type_id>
<type_id>asdasdasd</type_id>
<type_id>asdasdasd</type_id>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is very vague, here comes a vague answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.dom.minidom import *
xml = parse('1.xml')
name = xml.getElementsByTagName('type_id')
hashes = set()
for node in name:
    hashes.add(node.childNodes[0].data.encode('utf-8'))

print "\n".join(sorted(hashes))
```

Comment: this example in one line and described by me above places each type_id in a new line
conclusion of your example:
['asdasdasd', 'hashqwerty', 'qazwsxed5', etc
it is necessary to place each type_id in a new line:
asdasdasd
hashqwerty
qazwsxed5

Comment: You didn't mention you want one result per line. I updated the answer.

Comment: I apologize that didn't mention it earlier.
you are the best